# Too short? But there's nothing to say

Tags: discussion, answers

So https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/43694/4188 is marked for deletion for being too short. However a) it's not a comment, it's a complete, standalone, little known answer b) there's nothing more to say, am I to explain the UI of skypicker? Especially since it changed since the answer was written, it's quite futile.

Comment: Maybe the sentence you wrote in a comment (Skypicker is a flight search engine that allows you to enter "anywhere".), while not much longer, would help a bit by making the answer more self-contained?

Comment: I enjoyed your article and bookmarked your link.  Next time it might be beneficial to add a couple of sentences with any crap info about how the site works or how it is organized.  I know FGITW can get in the way sometimes but you can always amend by editing.

Comment: The turth is there's always something more to say, but that is true that say more wont help.

Answer (score 11):

> there's nothing more to say

Truth is: there's *always* something more to say. In my opinion the current answer provides no added value, although it has the potential to do so. As it stands it's more of an RTFM statement than a teach-a-man-to-fish answer. Even worse is the fact that it inevitably looks like a link-only answer. Therefore I personally agree with the delete vote - it should in fact be converted in a comment. Although I did not vote on it, I have however previously voted on many other similar answers.

To improve the quality of the answer you could either explain how the tool works, or why it works, or what's the advantage over the suggested solution. You could even cover all of the above.  Be scientific about it. It's worthy to note that the other answers to the question all offer more than (just) a link.

All in all the goal here on SE is to create quality answers to interesting, and valid, problems. RTFM (or link-only) answers don't quite cut it.

Comment: I agree with most of this, except it does not fit as a comment and definitely should not be posted as such. Either write an answer or don't, but don't post anything but critiques and requests for clarification in the comment section.

Answer (score 3):

There's always something you can say.

While looking at Skypicker I noticed several things about how the web site works, including one big gotcha which is likely to confuse people (and that they really should fix).

These notes are now [an edit to your answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/revisions/43694/3), because [that's how I roll](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/editing).